# How do I create a project in Visual Studio to use OpenMesh after I've built using CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I followed the directions for compiling OpenMesh on [Compiling OpenMesh Using CMake](http://www.openmesh.org/media/Documentations/OpenMesh-Doc-Latest/a00030.html) for Windows. I've went so far as to Configure and Generate. So I now have the OpenMesh.sln file. However, I don't know what the directions mean by "build OpenMesh from within Visual Studio using the newly created project file."

If anyone could explain the rest of this process to me. I'm not terribly tech-savvy when it comes to this setup part of the process.

Comment: OpenMesh.sln is a solution file for visual studio. double click on it, then visual studio will pop up. then press green arrow button on the toolbar in order to build a solution.

Comment: How do I create my own project that can use the library then? @nikitoz Do I just create a project within the solution file, or can I create one in a different solution that can still use the library?

Comment: It  does nott really matter, you just have to figure out how to link openmesh lib to your project, try googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the file using visual studio (By double clicking on it.)
2. Once visual studio opens find the `Build` tab at the top of the window.
3. Hit the `build solution` button and wait for the compiler to finish.

To change the build configuration find the drop down menu beside the `Local Windows Debugger` button. It should say `Debug`, click on it and select the option that you wish to use. For a solution created using CMake the options will usually be `Debug`, `MinSizeRel`, `Release` or `RelWithDebInfo`. You probably want to compile for at least `Debug` and `Release`.